# Restoring the model in tensorflow, Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable Error message

Tags: python, tensorflow, save, restore

I have trained my model and saved it with using

```
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.save(sess, '/final_model', global_step = i)
```

Then I rebuild the exact same graph and try to restore the model to reproduce my result, restoring is working but as long as try to access to any value of the network parameters or operations, it gives me an error saying trying to use the uninitialized variable.

After rebuilding the graph, the code I use to restore is:

```
    sess=tf.Session() 
    new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('final_model-699.meta')
    new_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
```

However, the following any of them give me an error of attempting to use uninitialized variable

```
    print(sess.run(weights['hidden1']))
    print(sess.run(loss_f, feed_dict={x: train_x, y_: train_y}))
```

Any idea?

As a simple example, here is the training and saving the model:

```
train_x = np.random.rand(200,2)
w= np.array([2,3])
train_y = np.dot(train_x, w)
train_y = np.reshape(train_y, [200,1])
feature_dim = 2
output_dim = 1

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, feature_dim])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, output_dim])
weights = {
    'hidden1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([feature_dim, output_dim], stddev=1 / np.sqrt(feature_dim)))
}    

def network1(data):
    output = tf.matmul(x, weights['hidden1'])
    return output
y = network1(x)

loss_f = output_dim * tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(y, y_))
optimizer_f = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(loss_f)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
for i in range(10000):
    batch_x = train_x
    batch_y = train_y
    sess.run(optimizer_f, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y_: batch_y})
    print(sess.run(loss_f, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y_: batch_y}))
saver.save(sess,'./savedmodel/', global_step = i)
```

Restoring and reproducing the result

```
import scipy.io
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import random
train_x = np.random.rand(200,2)
w= np.array([2,3])
train_y = np.dot(train_x, w)
train_y = np.reshape(train_y, [200,1])
feature_dim = 2
output_dim = 1
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, feature_dim])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, output_dim])


weights = {
    'hidden1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([feature_dim, output_dim], stddev=1 / np.sqrt(feature_dim)))
}

def network1(data):
    output = tf.matmul(x, weights['hidden1'])
    return output

y = network1(x)
loss_f = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(y, y_))
optimizer_f = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(loss_f)
sess = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./savedmodel/-9999.meta')
saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./savedmodel/'))

print(sess.run(loss_f, feed_dict={x: train_x, y_: train_y}))
```

The error:

```
FailedPreconditionErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-17910473afab> in <module>()
----> 1 print(sess.run(loss_f, feed_dict={x: train_x, y_: train_y}))

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    776     try:
    777       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 778                          run_metadata_ptr)
    779       if run_metadata:
    780         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    980     if final_fetches or final_targets:
    981       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
--> 982                              feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
    983     else:
    984       results = []

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1030     if handle is None:
   1031       return self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feed_dict, fetch_list,
-> 1032                            target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1033     else:
   1034       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feed_dict,

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1050         except KeyError:
   1051           pass
-> 1052       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1053 
   1054   def _extend_graph(self):

FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable
     [[Node: Variable/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@Variable"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](Variable)]]
     [[Node: Mean/_15 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_7_Mean", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op u'Variable/read', defined at:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 477, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 888, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 235, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 533, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2718, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2822, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-3-7d229041d9bb>", line 6, in <module>
    'hidden1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([feature_dim, output_dim], stddev=1 / np.sqrt(feature_dim)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 197, in __init__
    expected_shape=expected_shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 316, in _init_from_args
    self._snapshot = array_ops.identity(self._variable, name="read")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1338, in identity
    result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Identity", input=input, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable
     [[Node: Variable/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@Variable"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](Variable)]]
     [[Node: Mean/_15 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_7_Mean", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]


In [ ]:

print(sess.run(weights['hidden1']))
In [ ]:
```

same error for:

```
print(sess.run(weights['hidden1']))
​
```

Answer (score 3):

Ran into similar issue just recently with TF v1.5. It appears, that variables an ops should be added to a global collection for them to be restored properly. Below are two snippets for MNIST dataset that train, save and restore a model.

**Train and persist**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import os

train_dir = 'train'
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784], name='x')
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]), name='W')
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]), name='b')
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b, name='y')

saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.trainable_variables())
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

tf.add_to_collection('x', x)
tf.add_to_collection('yt', yt)
tf.add_to_collection('accuracy', accuracy)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    latest_checkpoint = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(train_dir)
    meta_path = '%s.meta' % latest_checkpoint

    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_path)
    saver.restore(sess, latest_checkpoint)

    x = tf.get_collection('x')[0]
    yt = tf.get_collection('yt')[0]
    accuracy = tf.get_collection('accuracy')[0]

    feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, yt: mnist.test.labels}

    print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict))
```

**Restore and evaluate**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import os

train_dir = 'train'
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    latest_checkpoint = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(train_dir)
    meta_path = '%s.meta' % latest_checkpoint

    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_path)
    saver.restore(sess, latest_checkpoint)

    x = tf.get_collection('x')[0]
    yt = tf.get_collection('yt')[0]
    accuracy = tf.get_collection('accuracy')[0]

    feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, yt: mnist.test.labels}

    print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict))
```

Here is a link to related [TF documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/meta_graph)

Answer (score 2):

Finally what I find is that seems every variable or operations we want to get access later need to be given a name, so is the placeholder, then we do not have the need to redefine the graph. The following is working finally, please give me more hints if there is an even more simple way to do that.

```
import scipy.io
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import random

train_x = np.random.rand(200,2)
w= np.array([2,3])
train_y = np.dot(train_x, w)
train_y = np.reshape(train_y, [200,1])
feature_dim = 2
output_dim = 1

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, feature_dim], name="input")
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, output_dim], name="output")
weights = {
    'hidden1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([feature_dim, output_dim], stddev=1 / np.sqrt(feature_dim)), name="weights")
}    

def network1(data):
    output = tf.matmul(data, weights['hidden1'])
    return output

y = network1(x)

loss_f = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(y, y_), name="op_to_restore")

optimizer_f = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(loss_f)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
for i in range(100):
    batch_x = train_x
    batch_y = train_y
    sess.run(optimizer_f, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y_: batch_y})
    print(sess.run(loss_f, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y_: batch_y}))
saver.save(sess,'./savedmodel/', global_step = i)     


with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./savedmodel/-99.meta')
    saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./savedmodel/'))
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    x = graph.get_tensor_by_name("input:0")
    y_ = graph.get_tensor_by_name("output:0")
    feed_dict={x: train_x, y_: train_y}
    op_to_restore = graph.get_tensor_by_name("op_to_restore:0")
    print(sess.run(op_to_restore, feed_dict))
```

Comment: As a better reference: [link](http://cv-tricks.com/tensorflow-tutorial/save-restore-tensorflow-models-quick-complete-tutorial/)

Comment: The error you experienced was because you created variables (`weights`) before restoring and did not initialize them before running the graph. It was not because you did not explicitly name the placeholders. TensorFlow will always pick a name, even if you don't specify one.